# My character is doing an unexpected 3rd jump in Unity2D

Tags: c#, 2d, controllers, unity-game-engine

**Hello!**

I am currently working on a 2D plattformer game in the Unity engine, where I have created a character that can preform a doubblejump.
It all worked pretty good in the beginning, but I have now realized that there is a game breaking bug that makes him able to preform a third jump (for some reason). And I can't for the sake of it figure out what the problem is.

**PlayerController.cs**

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour {

    /*
    TODO: Find out why the character ocationally
    gets 3 jumps instead of 2.
    I think it's the "isGrounded" that returns
    a false posetive.
    */

[Header("Ground Recognition")]
public BoxCollider2D groundCollider;
public LayerMask groundAbles;

[Header("Audio")]
public GameObject jumpSound = null;

[Header("Visual")]
public GameObject jumpEffect = null;


float speed = 5f;
int maxJumps = 2;
int currentJumps = 0;

bool isGrounded = false;
float boundsLength = 0;

Vector3 movement;
// Use this for initialization
void Start () {

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update() {
    CheckGroundCollision();
    JumpLogic();

    movement = new Vector3(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * speed, 0, 0);
    movement *= Time.deltaTime;
    transform.position += movement;

    CheckGroundCollision();
}

void CheckGroundCollision()
{
    isGrounded = groundCollider.IsTouchingLayers(groundAbles);
}

void JumpLogic()
{

    if (isGrounded)
        currentJumps = 0;

    if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump") && currentJumps < maxJumps)
    {
        GameObject newJumpSound = (GameObject)GameObject.Instantiate(jumpSound, (Vector2)transform.position, transform.rotation);
        GameObject newJumpEffect = (GameObject)GameObject.Instantiate(jumpEffect, (Vector2)transform.position - new Vector2(0, 0.25f), transform.rotation);
        GameObject.Destroy(newJumpEffect, 0.2f);
        GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = new Vector2(GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity.x, 0);
        GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(new Vector2(0, 10), ForceMode2D.Impulse);
        currentJumps++;
        CheckGroundCollision();
    }
}
}
```

All help is appreciated!

Comment: just as a test, try to set maxjumps to 1. and see if you can get 2 jumps. it might be an order of operations issue and you are getting isGrounded = true after pressing jump but before you leave contact with the ground.

Comment: Can you debug or print some info while it's running?  I'd be curious if `isGrounded` is causing any issues and resetting the `currentJumps` prematurely.

Comment: I have tested the theory, and the issue is indeed based upon the currentJumps being prematurely reset!

Answer (score 1):

In `void JumpLogic()`, you're calling

```
currentJumps++;
CheckGroundCollision();
```

The very first time you press the jump-key, `currentJumps` becomes 1 (currentJumps++), but then `isGrounded` becomes true again (because the physics has not been applied yet in the current frame, and the character is still touching the ground layermask). So the next time `JumpLogic()` is called, `currentJumps` is reset to zero because of `if (isGrounded) currentJumps = 0;` before running the jump-key code.

I suggest removing the last call to `CheckGroundCollision();` inside of `void JumpLogic()`.
They are both called inside `Update()` anyway, in an order that looks like it would work.

I hope that helps!

**UPDATE:**
I just noticed you're also calling `CheckGroundCollision();` a second time inside `Update()` itself. That would be resetting the jump variable too.

Try this modification of your original code:

```
void Update() {
    CheckGroundCollision();
    JumpLogic();

    movement = new Vector3(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * speed, 0, 0);
    movement *= Time.deltaTime;
    transform.position += movement;

    //** NOTE- REMOVED THIS LINE
}

...

void JumpLogic()
{

    if (isGrounded)
        currentJumps = 0;

    if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump") && currentJumps < maxJumps)
    {
        GameObject newJumpSound = (GameObject)GameObject.Instantiate(jumpSound, (Vector2)transform.position, transform.rotation);
        GameObject newJumpEffect = (GameObject)GameObject.Instantiate(jumpEffect, (Vector2)transform.position - new Vector2(0, 0.25f), transform.rotation);
        GameObject.Destroy(newJumpEffect, 0.2f);
        GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = new Vector2(GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity.x, 0);
        GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(new Vector2(0, 10), ForceMode2D.Impulse);
        currentJumps++;

        //** NOTE- REMOVED THIS LINE
    }
}
```

I hope that helps!

Comment: I tried removing it, but the issue persists. I have recently confirmed that the issue is that my currentJumps gets reset prematurely.

Comment: Try changing the order of `CheckGroundCollision();` and `JumpLogic();` inside Update... along with the change I suggested above.

Comment: That made matters worse. Now, the tripple jump works like the double jump should. (He is always able to make a tripple)

Comment: @riddarn97 Check my updated answer. I realised you were doing something, and wanted to suggest code edits.

Comment: That didn't work either. I have no idea whats so wrong with my code...
This behavior is so unexpected it's almost comical.

Comment: @riddarn97 I suggest using Debug.Log() to find out where the values might be changing against your intentions.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest letting the collider dictate to the player controller the state of isGrounded rather than querying the collider.  For example, continuing on [andeart's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5095609/andeart) suggestions, your code could look more like the following

```
void Update() {
    JumpLogic();

    movement = new Vector3(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * speed, 0, 0);
    movement *= Time.deltaTime;
    transform.position += movement;
}

//let the collider indicate to the player controller when
//a collision occurs, then determine if this collision is relevant
void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D coll) {
    if(coll.IsTouchingLayers(groundAbles))    
      isGrounded = true;

    // or do some other check using layers or tags ....
}

void JumpLogic()
{
    if (isGrounded)
        currentJumps = 0;

    if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump") && currentJumps < maxJumps)
    {
        GameObject newJumpSound = (GameObject)GameObject.Instantiate(jumpSound, (Vector2)transform.position, transform.rotation);
        GameObject newJumpEffect = (GameObject)GameObject.Instantiate(jumpEffect, (Vector2)transform.position - new Vector2(0, 0.25f), transform.rotation);
        GameObject.Destroy(newJumpEffect, 0.2f);
        GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = new Vector2(GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity.x, 0);
        GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(new Vector2(0, 10), ForceMode2D.Impulse);
        currentJumps++;
    }
}
```

See [Collider2D.IsTouchingLayers](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider2D.IsTouchingLayers.html) particularly the bottom paragraph which implies that the IsTouchingLayers method may not give the most acurate result with respect to the collider.